# NAA flag declined - Completely different tech

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

The question in question is [Timer stops at wrong time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54290565/6144259) which is relating to a `Winforms` timer.

The answer is shown below.

[image: The answer the flag was declined on]

I don't see a copy-paste chunk of code using completely unrelated technologies as a real attempt to answer the question.

[image: Answer and not-answer]

(taken from answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/6144259))

So why doesn't the not-an-answer flag apply here?

Is any flag appropriate or is downvoting enough?

Comment: Reading the question, it seems to be some winforms...controlling a web browser?  That could lead to the web-based answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Later on in the [very answer you reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/6144259) it says

> Do not use the "not an answer" flag for wrong answers. Moderators do not judge the technical correctness of answers.

You're left with downvoting as your response. Sometimes such answers are useful if only to say, if you thought of solving it this way, think again.

Comment: So the flag is purely for things that are **entirely** not an answer such as "I like cats"? I suppose although clear to me, the people looking at the review queue may not know the difference between ASP and Winforms and so shouldn't make them judge through NAA.. Thank you for your insight!

Comment: Indeed, although it's more common to have to flag questions written in the answer field as "not an answer".